# Sprayed foam sealant into window blind's headrail, immobilizing it. Blinds are also screwed directly into frame. How to remove (has picture)

Tags: windows, blinds, sealant

Trying to seal window crevices, I accidentally sprayed into window blinds headrail whose top is exposed. The crevice is so narrow I couldn't see into the *top* of the headrail, so I forgot it was open.

[image]

It's already dried and I can't use my window blinds any more (*pull cord is stuck*). I can't easily cut out the sealant because there's no room to look inside the blind's head-rail.

**Important Note** The guys Home Depot sent to install these blinds (decade ago) installed it incorrectly I just discovered. They *did not* install any brackets to push the blind's headrail into. Instead, they *screwed the headrail directly into the window frame*. I was young and didn't think anything of it until this problem arisen. In order to unscrew it, I have to access the top of the headrail, covered in foam sealant. I can't get to all the foam sealant because the crevice is too narrow to reach.

The metallic blind head-rail needs to be cut right, to access the screw?

Comment: that is an option

Comment: "*Should I get someone to saw through the metallic blind head-rail?*" Why, What will that accomplish, will get the cord unstuck ?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you've sprayed expanding foam into the head of your blinds. It has now fully encased all the working mechanism of the blinds - the rods, gears, strings, etc.

- You could take the blinds down, remove as many external parts as you can, then with a series of small picks, knives, scoops, etc. dig at the foam for several hours, attempting to get it out of every nook and cranny.
- Once you get to pieces like gears, you can attempt to disassemble the mechanism to carefully scrape all the foam off the gears to ensure they'll mesh properly when called upon to turn and not to jam up against a wayward blob of foam.
- When you find a pull string, you can attempt to carefully scrape the foam off the string with a putty knife, your fingers/fingernails, or whatever else you can come up with to get the foam out of the threads.

Since, at this particular point in history, many of us find ourselves under involuntary house arrest, you may well have plenty of time to undertake this endeavor and find you have nothing better to do.

If, however, you value your sanity and have better things to do with your time, I'd suggest:

- Pitch the blinds
- Buy and install a new set
- Consider this a lesson learned

It is fairly simple to remove most window blinds, generally just pull it from 2 or 3 clips. It's usually worth doing so for any window-area maintenance to prevent damage to the blinds as repairing them is generally a pain.

---

#### Based on updated info provided in a comment on this post:

The OP indicated that these blinds weren't installed properly in the first place. Instead of using the proper clips to mount them, it seems that the head unit was screwed directly into the window frame. In this case, cutting the blinds apart to get to the foam hiding the screws is probably the only way.

Whether using a Sawzall™-type reciprocating saw, an oscillating flush-cutter, or even a manual hacksaw, the logical way would be to slip the blade between the top of the head unit and the window frame, slide it along until it catches, then start sawing to cut through the obstruction (which may be a screw, or just a snug part of the blinds/frame interface).

The drawback to this method is that the blade is *very* likely to damage the window frame. At a minimum, you'll end up scraping up the finish. Worst case, you may cut into the sash frame itself, and if it's vinyl, you may cut into one of the open pockets inside and really destroy some of the structural integrity of the sash.

If you happen to know roughly *where* the screws were, it *might* be reasonable to dig the foam out around this area, then unscrew the mounting screws. In order to prevent damage to the frame/sashes, this may be the *only* way to safely remove the head.

You might, if you're careful, be able to cut off the front of the head to give you more access to the foam to make it easier to cut it out to get to the screws. If you happen to know "the moron" (OP's words) who installed this, he may be able to give you a rough idea where he put the screws to minimize the amount of foam you'll have to remove.

Comment: Yeah, your blinds are toast.

Comment: "It is fairly simple to remove most window blinds, generally just pull it from 2 or 3 clips"   ----      

The problem is, there are no clips. The moron who originally installed it, screwed the the back of the headrail directly into the window frame using a drill. In hindsight I'm a bigger moron assuming he knew what he was doing. There were all these leftover brackets he said wasn't necessary. Now it seems I have to cut through metal just to access the screws.

Comment: Ah, yeah, @NoonTime, it's highly unlikely that this was installed properly. This would have been good info to have been put into your OP. You are correct, you will probably have to cut the blinds apart to get to the foam covering the screws so you can get this mess out of the way to properly install their replacements. Don't worry, we've all screwed up _something_ and ended up having to replace it.

Comment: @NoonTime please note some updates in the answer